# Transpiller and Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, coffeescript, typescript, babeljs

I want to use for my new project BabelJS, but I have a big requirement: It must be  executable on IE8.

**PROBLEM**: Babel compiles ES6 to ES5. ES5 support on IE8 is poor.

Do you know alternatives to Babel that allow me to write "OOP" code, easily debuggable and "IE8 friendly"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Typescript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript), it give you possibility to build [EcmaScript 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript#Compatibility_with_JavaScript) compatibility code.

All that you need to [getting started](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Tutorial) with TypeScript - are create simple project in Visual Studio (or VSCode/Sublime/WebStorm), and configure `tsconfig.json` like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es3",
    "declaration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "listFiles": true,
    "outDir": "",
    "out": "./Compiled/myfile.js",
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "files": [
    "myfile.ts"
  ]
}
```

Good Luck!

### Related resources

1. [TypeScript in WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/typescript-support.html)
2. [TypeScript Sublime Plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin)
3. [TypeScript in VS Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/04/30/using-typescript-in-visual-studio-code.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Babel has a 'loose' mode for several of its transformations that causes them to generate code that uses fewer fancier ES5 features, at the expense of less spec compatibility. Generally if you enable them, and avoid ES5-specific syntax like getters and setters, things should work in IE8.

Much of this is covered in [the caveats page](http://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/caveats/).